# Healthcare IT is still displayed as private beta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, beta-phase

At the bottom of [this list](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) today Healthcare IT is still displayed as private beta, despite it is in public beta for more than a whole day now.

**Edit:**

I guess I was fooled by this count down 3 days ago:

[image: Area51 sez, public beta starts in seconds]

Comment: Heh... Uh, oops!

Comment: I think I saw the same sort of count down on dba, bat there the delay was only some hours and I thought it was caused by technical reason and not the missing activity of the beta participants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still in private beta, building up momentum...

We'll kick it into public as soon as the site has had enough time to build up a catalog of questions and answers suitable for exhibiting its budding strength to the unwashed masses. Stay tuned... And thanks for your participation thus far!

Answer (score 2):

http://healthcareit.stackexchange.com/users/login:

> Warning: this site is currently in private beta for at least a few more days.

You would appear to be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Enough time has passed that this site is *actually* in public beta. Everything seems to be working right. This is really now "too localized," not "by design."